# Footer div not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns

```css
.bookingTotals.middleRow {
  height: 315px;
  bottom: 400px;
}

.bookingTotals.row {
  height: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 920px;
  /*margin-right: 55px;*/
}
```

```html
<div id "myParent">
  <div style="float: left; width: 400px;">
    //some stuff
    <div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 400px;">
        //some stuff
        <div>
          <div style="float: left; width: 400px;">
            <div style="height:50px;">
              //top stuff
            </div>
            <div class="bookingTotals middleRow">
              //middle stiff that fills the gap
            </div>
            <div class="bookingTotals row">
              //bottom stuff that i want fixed to the bottom
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to split the last column into 3 layers where the top and bottom `div` heights are known. So I want the middle `div` to fill the space between.

What actually happens is that this footer `div` is displayed outside `myParent` as if it had no relation to it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first  2 `float: left` `div`s aren't closed in the question. Did you copy your source correctly?

Comment: Hi I typed if fresh. Sorry I will correct when home. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `bottom` property you also need to specify `position`.
I used `calc` to fill the space. In this way, the height of the middle row will depend on the screen size.

```css
.top-row {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.bookingTotals.middleRow {
  height: calc(100vh - 400px);
  background: orange;
}

.bookingTotals.row {
  height: 290px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="myParent">
  <div>
    some stuff
    <div>
      <div style="width: 400px;">
        some stuff
        <div>
          <div style="width: 400px;">
            <div class="top-row">
              top stuff
            </div>
            <div class="bookingTotals middleRow">
              middle stiff that fills the gap
            </div>
            <div class="bookingTotals row">
              bottom stuff that i want fixed to the bottom
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks will check this out tomorrow

Comment: hi, running that cod snippet gives an odd result.  Try it and you wil see

Comment: @AndrewSimpson open it in full page or copy the code to your html.

Comment: Hi, yes i did, and it was the same result

Comment: Hi, can you explain what is the odd result?

Comment: Hi, the result is exactly the same as if you run the code snippet via this site

Comment: I am now stripping away all my other html tags to see if a property is affecting yours. i will update shortly :)

Comment: took some tinkering but in essense u were correct so thanks

Answer (score 2):

I took some liberty with your height so it would show better.

Use CSS for everything, not put in the markup.  Use classes for that.

I make the assumption you want the text in the last one at the bottom so I added a `span` around it and used `align-self: flex-end;` at the `flex` end for the row.
Background color added for clarity of the solution.

```css
#myParent {
  width: 100px;
}

.rowthing {
  width: 410px;
}

.holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 350px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.things {
  display: flex;
}

.topstuff {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddeeee;
}

.bookingTotals.middleRow {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.bookingTotals.middleRow span {
  align-self: center;
}

.bookingTotals.bottom {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #eeeedd;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bookingTotals.bottom span {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id "myParent">
  <div class="rowthing">
    //some stuff1
  </div>
  <div class="rowthing">
    //some stuff2
  </div>
  <div class="rowthing holder">
    <div class="things topstuff">
      //top stuff
    </div>
    <div class="things bookingTotals middleRow">
      <span> //middle stiff that fills the gap<span>
    </div>
    <div class="things bookingTotals bottom">
      <span>bottom stuff that i want fixed to the bottom<span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am away from pc will look at this tomorrow. Thanks very much